# Install correct version of NVIDIA on cent os 6.3?

Tags: centos, nvidia

I want to install NVIDIA drivers for cent os 6.3. My laptop is Toshiba Satellite series L750. The brightness control doesn't works in the system. It is 100% brightness now, so difficult in working for long time since am a developer. The only way it worked was to install the NVIDIA drivers and editing the NVIDIA xconfig file. It worked two times earlier. But am not sure about which version of NVIDIA to install. Once installed wrong version the system wont boot in graphics mode and I have to reinstall. Please help. I always prefer to use linux but this is the major problem in all linux distors am facing.

Comment: Perhaps you should update to 6.7 first and install all current patches. Use 3 as additional boot kernel parameter to start up without gui.

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS I think it's best to download the driver from the Nvidia webiste. Not sure if there is a binary RPM package for Centos somewhere out there.

To install the driver from Nvidia you also will have to install `gcc` and `kernel-sources` and I would recommend to install `dmks` as well. 
Then install the package as root.

> `chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run`
>   `./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run --dmks`

The `dkms` stuff should normally take care in case of an kernel update, that the Nvidia driver module is ported to the new kernel automatically. Otherwise you will have to run the installer everytime you have updated to a new kernel.
As I don't have access to a CentOS machine right now, it might that the package names differ.